# Principal Component Analysis (PCA) vs. Extra Tree Classifier for Data Reduction

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset that consists of 13 columns and I wanted to use PCA for data reduction to remove unwanted columns. My problem is PCA doesn't really show columns names but PC1 PC2 etc. I found out extra tree classifier does the same thing but does indicate the variation of each column. I just wanted to make sure if they both have the same objective or are they different in their outcome. Also would anyone suggest a better methods for Data Reduction?

My last question is that I have a code for Extra tree classifier and wanted to confirm if it was correct or not?

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest

from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier 



df = pd.read_csv('D:\\Project\\database\\5-FINAL2\\Final After Simple Filtering.csv')

extra_tree_forest = ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators = 500, 
                                        criterion ='entropy', max_features = 'auto') 

extra_tree_forest.fit(df)

feature_importance = extra_tree_forest.feature_importances_ 

feature_importance_normalized = np.std([tree.feature_importances_ for tree in 
                                        extra_tree_forest.estimators_], 
                                        axis = 0) 

plt.bar(df.columns, feature_importance_normalized) 
plt.xlabel('Feature Labels') 
plt.ylabel('Feature Importances') 
plt.title('Comparison of different Feature Importances') 
plt.show()
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods are very different.

PCA doesn't show you the feature names because dimensionality reduction with PCA doesn't really have anything to do with the relative importance of the features. PCA takes the original data and transforms it into a space where each new 'feature' (principal component) is independent of the others, and you can tell how important each principal component is to faithfully representing the data based on its corresponding eigenvalue. Removing the least important principal components reduces dimensionality in principal component space, but not in the original feature space - so you need to do PCA on all future data, too, and then perform all your classification on the (shortened) principal component vectors.

An extra tree classifier trains an entire classifier on your data, so it's much more powerful than just dimensionality reduction. However, it does seem closer to what you're looking for, since the feature importance does directly tell you how relevant each feature is when making a classification.

Note that in PCA, the principal components with the highest eigenvalues contribute the most to accurately **reconstructing** the data. This is not the same as contributing the most to accurately **classifying** the data. The extra tree classifier is the reverse: it tells you what features are most important when **classifying** the data, not when **reconstructing** it.

Basically, if you think you have a representative dataset right now and are comfortable only storing variables that are relevant to classifying the data you already have, dimensionality reduction with extra trees is a good choice for you. If you just want to faithfully represent the data with less space without being overly concerned about the effects on classification, PCA is the better choice. Dimensionality reduction with PCA will often also help remove irrelevant features from the original data, but that's not what it's optimized for.

Comment: So In my case using extra tree classifier would be the better choice for what I need to do ( reconstrucing/removing columns that are not important compared to other)?

Comment: @AliYoussef It really depends on how confident you are about how representative your current dataset is. If you use the extra tree classifier and only store columns based on how important they are for classification based on your current dataset, you'd better hope that you'll never be interested in the columns you dropped.

Comment: So I have decided to use extra tree classifier and found out that few of my columns had less than 2% of feature importance compared to others. I do one have simple question I have asked here:
( https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451732/feature-reduction-normalization) if possible you know the answer do you mind checking it out please? Thank you very much for your explanations as well.